# Rails ActiveStorage: How to delete all variants of a specific Attachment completely (all ActiveStorage DB records AND files, except for the original)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

How do I delete all variants (but not the original upload) of a specific Attachment completely, meaning:

- All DB records in all `ActiveStorage` tables, AND
- All their associated files in the folder `/storage`)?

The model scenario is: `Avatar has_one_attached :file`

I have tried...

```
ActiveStorage::VariantRecord.where(blob_id: @avatar.file.blob.id).destroy_all
```

...but this does apparently NEITHER delete entries in the table `active_storage_blobs` NOR their associated files in the folder `/storage`.

(Context: I need to destroy the "old" variants before they are recreated from the original uploaded file, because Rails does apparently not replace the "old" ones automatically.)

Comment: Your query should delete active_storage_blobs and files of that variant

Comment: @mechnicov - I've tried it multiple times: It deletes only the `active_storage_attachments` records and the `active_storage_variant_records` records, but not the `active_storage_blobs` records. And the files themselves remain present also. So this does not seem to work with Rails `7.0.4.3`. (IMHO, Rails should have a method `.purge_variants`, since this use case probably happens fairly often.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call [`ActiveStorage::Attached::One#purge`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/One.html#method-i-purge) on given attachment

```rb
@avatar.file.purge
```

This directly purges the attachment (i.e. destroys the blob and attachment with all variants and deletes the files on the service).

The complete list of steps could then look like this:

```rb
# 1. Collect data of the original file
image_io =     @avatar.file.download
content_type = @avatar.file.content_type
filename =     @avatar.file.filename.to_s

# 2. Purge all DB records/files/variants of the original file
@avatar.file.purge

# 3. Create a copy of the original file
new_blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.create_and_upload!(
  io: StringIO.new(image_io),
  filename: filename,
  content_type: content_type
)

# 4. Attach the new file
@avatar.file.attach(new_blob)

# 5. Create the variants of the new file
#  [...]
```

Comment: Thanks - but I still need to retain the original file that was uploaded, because the variants must be recreated (your suggestion would destroy the original as well).

Comment: @TomDogg this is the correct answer but you will have to make a copy of the image you want to keep before purging then re-attach the copy

Answer (score 0):

This will remove variants you want to refresh:

```ruby
Avatar.find_each.each do |avatar| 
  avatar.file.variant(:display_variant_1).image&.record&.destroy
  avatar.file.variant(:display_variant_2).image&.record&.destroy 
end
```